# How could Opera put facebook messenger into their browser? No API available

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to this article, opera has put facebook messenger etc into their browser.

https://www.theverge.com/2017/5/10/15604878/opera-messaging-sidebar-reborn-whatsapp-messenger-telegram

As far as I know Facebook depricated this feature a while back.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/user/inbox

Comment: Who says that is using any official APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Looks to me like [messenger.com](http://www.messenger.com) in a webview.**

You can easily access facbook messenger from a browser if you're logged into FB and visit messenger.com, or m.me. It even has the site title at the top in the demo gif announcing the feature.